# Определение указываемой структуры

Tags: c

У меня есть две структуры `struct first f;` `struct second s;` и указатель на одну из них `pointer`. Как выяснить, на которую pointer указывает?

Comment: А язык какой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Представьте, что вы работаете с памятью. Указатель — это всего лишь адрес в памяти. Приведя его к определенному типу и попробовав обратиться к полям структуры, вы получите какие-либо данные, но не факт, что они будут правильными. Мой совет — не делайте таких сложных вещей.

**UPD.** Можно, конечно, в каждую структуру встроить в качестве первого байта поле, которое будет указывать на тип структуры.

Comment: Если порыться в исходниках руби, то помойму там именно так сделано. в стиле: struct Object {byte type;} struct String {Object *value;}. приводишь к Object. и смотришь какой у тебя тип.

Comment: Поскольку в C нет RTTI, то специальное поле в структуре - это правильный подход.

Answer (score 3):

Видимо как-то так:

```
struct first f;
struct second s;

void f(void* pointer)
{
    if (pointer == &f)
       printf("first\n");
    if (pointer == &s)
       printf("second\n");

}
```

Вообще вопрос поставлен не корректно) Оч сложно понять что имеется ввиду)

Comment: ах вот что имелось в виду %)

Answer (score 0):

Если речь именно о структурах - то, очевидно :

```
switch (pointer) {
case &struct1: ...
case &struct2: ...
}
```

Возможно, в C нельзя сделать `switch` по указателям, но - думаю, идея ясна.

А если речь о типах - то стоит приюзать перегрузку (ЕМНИП, так можно же)

```
void type_sensitive(struct1* data) { ... }
void type_sensitive(struct2* data) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

Точно конечно не помню, но может попробовать привести указатель к одному из типов, если адрес будет равен NULL, то значит указатель другого типа.

Comment: это в С++ через dynamic_cast можно

Comment: Не сработает. Статическое приведение типов (мы же о Си говорим, судя по меткам?) просто сдвигает значение указателя, прибавляя или вычитая некое число. Корректность получившегося указателя при этом не проверяется.